# Handle legacy URLs that now are not found 3 years after migrating site from Blogspot to WordPress

Tags: seo, wordpress, migration, blogspot

Google still detect old URLs from blogspot:

- `/2016/07/example-title-post-here.html`
- `/2016/07/example-title-post-here.html?m=1`

But when I try access old data URLs, it's already a 404.
That leads to so many anomalies crawling and Google sometimes detects 5xx errors.

In WordPress I have already been using permalinks like `/%postname%/` for 3 years. I have thousands of URLs like that.

**What best choice for that problem**?

1. Redirect all with 301 to homepage
2. Send "410 Gone" status for those URLs
3. Something else

Answer (score 1):

You don't list the best choice: **Individually redirect each page to its new URL**. That is really the only good choice for preserving SEO and user experience.

Thousands of URLs is a lot, but you have some options.   You could manually go through and map all the redirects by hand and add them to your .*htaccess* file.  Doing so would probably only take a couple of days of work.

[wpbeginner has a tutorial](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-switch-from-blogger-to-wordpress-without-losing-google-rankings/) about migrating from Blogspot to Wordpress.   They recommend this [Blogger to WordPress redirect plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blogger-to-wordpress-redirection/).  It appears to work by installing in WordPress and generating code that you paste into Blogger.